# Instrumented dojo application terminates with scripterror:21 on recording start

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww

Worklight studio is on FP1 of WL6.1
MTWW is on 8.5.10.v20140221_0011
Application runs fine on Android 4.1.2 when non-instrumented.
MTWW also looks ok (connectivity to workbench, replacement of normal application by instrumented one)

Problem is, when recording starts - it gets freezed. 
The only relevant messages on LogCat is scripterror:21 from web console

The behaviour is similar to dojo missing resources but dojo works fine on un-instrumented version.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

This is a defect in the current release of MTWW (v8.5.10). An iFix was provided.

If anyone else (IBM customer or business partner) will require it:

- the next release will contain the fix
- a PMR (support ticket) can be opened